# C# Multi-threading update/read from main array

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm working on an app that will be executing multiple searches at the same time. Each one will be on it's own thread. Each thread will need to check an array to see if a result has already showed up. If it hasn't shown that result then show the result to the user and add it to the main array. So each thread needs to be able to read and write to the main array at the same time.

I'm coming from a PHP and JS background so I'm very new to threading and C#. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I'm using BackgroundWorker to multithread.

Comment: Which .NET version are you targeting?

Comment: I think you should implement some kind of Monitor (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)) to moderate access to your array

Comment: Doesn't a monitor lock the resource? What happens when another thread tries to access a locked resource, does it wait or error out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the rationale behind using `BackgroundWorker` when you're going for .NET 4.5

So, if I may add:

1. Do yourself a favor and use [`Task Parallel Library`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) (`Task.Run`/`Task.Factory.StartNew()`, `Parallel.For`/`Parallel.ForEach` depending on your needs).
2. You will either have to lock (by e.g. [`lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or [`SlimReadWriterLock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx)) or use a collection from  [`Collections.Concurrent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287108.aspx) namespace.

Now it's a bit of a lengthy topic to go on, so if you have any further doubts or questions, I will edit the answer appropriately. There are a few examples on the MSDN pages I have linked.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm looking into TPL now.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember rightly, an "array" in PHP is similar to a dictionary, in terms of being a key/value lookup data structure.

In that case, and given that you're using a pretty recent version of .Net, "[ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx)" from the "[System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx)" namespace sounds like the easiest option to use.

Good luck,